# GridView custom adapter has CastClassException

Tags: android, gridview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to vaguely use a [tutorial](http://javatechig.com/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android) about creating your own custom adapter for `GridView`, but having problem with one single line, that came from tutorial in my adapter, but I keep getting error on it. `PhotoGridItem item =  photos.get(position);` If I leave the line as is, it is red and says "incompatible types, expecting `PhotoGridItem`, found `Object`". So I try casting `(PhotoGridItem)` to it, which gets rid of the error, but then at runtime I get a `ClassCastException` that says "cannot cast Bitmap to `PhotoGridItem`". But I don't know what else to try.

Any ideas? Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

As suggested I changed all of my `ArrayList()` to `ArrayList<PhotoGridItem>`, then I changed my bitmap image output method slightly to `photoList.add(new PhotoGridItem(bitmap));` No compile errors, but still get `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.Bitmap cannot be cast to org.azurespot.cutecollection.PhotoGridItem` at the line in my adapter: `PhotoGridItem item = photos.get(position);`. Code below has been updated.

**PhotoTab.java**

```
    package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/8/15.
 */
public class PhotoTab extends Fragment{

    private GridView gridView;
    File[] files;
    ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> photoList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

    public PhotoTab(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_tab, container, false);

        // with fragments, make sure you include the rootView when finding id
        gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.photo_grid);
        adapter = new GridViewPhotoAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.photo_grid_item,
                                                                    loadSDCard());
        // Set the Adapter to GridView
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // add the default icons remaining, to GridView, if less than 24 files on SD card
        for (int i = 0; i < (24 - photoList.size()); i++) {

            adapter.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_photo_placeholder));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            i++;
        }

        return v;
    }


    private ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> loadSDCard(){

        try {
            // gets directory CutePhotos from sd card
            File baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File cutePhotoDir = new File(baseDir, "/Documents/CutePhotos");
            // lists all files in CutePhotos, loads in Files[] array
            files = cutePhotoDir.listFiles();


            for (File singleFile : files) {
                String filePath = singleFile.getAbsolutePath();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                photoList.add(new PhotoGridItem(bitmap));
            }

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return photoList;
    }

}
```

**GridViewPhotoAdapter.java**

```
    package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
* Created by mizu on 2/5/15.
*/
public class GridViewPhotoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    public Context context;
    private int resourceId;
    private ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> photos = new ArrayList<>();


    public GridViewPhotoAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> photos) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, photos);
        this.context = context;
        this.resourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.photos = photos;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.photo_grid_view);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        PhotoGridItem item = photos.get(position);

        holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());

        return row;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
    }

}
```

**PhotoGridItem.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 3/19/15.
 */
public class PhotoGridItem {

    private Bitmap image;

    public PhotoGridItem(Bitmap image) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

}
```

**Logcat**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.azurespot, PID: 5080
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.Bitmap cannot be cast to org.azurespot.cutecollection.PhotoGridItem
            at org.azurespot.cutecollection.GridViewPhotoAdapter.getView(GridViewPhotoAdapter.java:49)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2791)
            at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1065)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1456)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2317)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1412)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1613)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1270)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6691)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5731)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that you have made a `ArrayList of objects` instead of ArrayList of PhotoGridItem

So convert it to `ArrayList<PhotoGridItem>`

> Expanation

That's because you did not specify your `ArrayList` to contain `PhotoGridItem` like `ArrayList<PhotoGridItem>` instead you specified nothing and by default it is Object only and gives back Object.Make a list of `PhotoGridItem` like ArrayList

> Changes

**In your fragment class instance variables**

```
ArrayList photoList = new ArrayList();
```

**To**

```
ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> photoList = new ArrayList<PhotoGridItem>();
```

Change this

```
private ArrayList loadSDCard(){

    try {
        // gets directory CutePhotos from sd card
        File baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File cutePhotoDir = new File(baseDir, "/Documents/CutePhotos");
        // lists all files in CutePhotos, loads in Files[] array
        files = cutePhotoDir.listFiles();


        for (File singleFile : files) {
            String filePath = singleFile.getAbsolutePath();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            photoList.add(bitmap);
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return photoList;
}
```

**TO**

```
private ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> loadSDCard(){

    try {
        // gets directory CutePhotos from sd card
        File baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File cutePhotoDir = new File(baseDir, "/Documents/CutePhotos");
        // lists all files in CutePhotos, loads in Files[] array
        files = cutePhotoDir.listFiles();


        for (File singleFile : files) {
            String filePath = singleFile.getAbsolutePath();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            photoList.add(new PhotoGridItem(bitmap));
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return photoList;
}
```

Change this

```
private ArrayList photos = new ArrayList();


public GridViewPhotoAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList photos) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, photos);
    this.context = context;
    this.resourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.photos = photos;
}
```

**To**

```
private ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> photos = new ArrayList<PhotoGridItem>();


public GridViewPhotoAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> photos) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, photos);
    this.context = context;
    this.resourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.photos = photos;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it got rid of the error, but then at runtime I got the ClassCastException again. `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.Bitmap cannot be cast to org.azurespot.cutecollection.PhotoGridItem` So then I changed the ArrayList in my main activity to `ArrayList<PhotoGridItem>` and changed how I add a `Bitmap` to the `ArrayList` like this: `photoList.add(new PhotoGridItem(bitmap));` but still getting the exact same `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Okay, just got your new answer, going to try it now!

Comment: I have added the required changes, try now.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the areas to change. Still getting an error though: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.Bitmap cannot be cast to org.azurespot.cutecollection.PhotoGridItem`.

Comment: Paste here your GridViewAdapter class becuase you may not have done changes there as i said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73388/discussion-between-cafebabe1991-and-noni-a).

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned your arraylist declaration is wrong. ArrayList are generic type as they can contain any objects of same type. But you will need to provide the data type information that this arraylist should hold.

```
ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> photoList = new ArrayList<PhotoGridItem>();
GridViewPhotoAdapter adapter; // this should not be ArrayAdapter
```

The problem with the tutorial site is that generic types like  **< Integer >** was probably treated like html tags like < body >. I found that Stackoverflow also has this problem.

Comment: Thanks, I did change all my `ArrayList` to `ArrayList<PhotoGridItem>` but still getting the cast error, saying I can't go from `Bitmap` to `PhotoGridItem`. Doesn't make sense, everything is the right type now. :(

Answer (score 0):

Change your `getView` method of `GridViewPhotoAdapter` as mentioned below. You are adding `Bitmap` directly into `ArrayList`. You did not used `PhotoGridItem` within `loadSDCard` method. If you want `PhotoGridItem` means try to populate your `ArrayList` with `PhotoGridItem`.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.photo_grid_view);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        //PhotoGridItem item =  photos.get(position);

        //holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());

        holder.image.setImageBitmap(photos.get(position));
        return row;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error that says "`setImageBitmap` in `ImageView` cannot be applied to `Object`". I don't know why they are thinking that is an `Object`. The `photos.get(position)` part, I think.

Comment: That's because you did not specify your ArrayList to contain PhotoGridItem like ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> instead you specified nothing @NoniA.

Comment: change your `private ArrayList photos = new ArrayList();` of `GridViewPhotoAdapter ` as `private ArrayList<Bitmap> photos = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();` and also change `ArrayList photoList = new ArrayList();` of `PhotoTab` as  `ArrayList<Bitmap> photoList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();`. If you want to use `PhotoGridItem` replace `Bitmap` `ArrayList` with `PhotoGridItem` `ArrayList`

Comment: Thanks, still getting an error on that one line `PhotoGridItem item = photos.get(position);`, but this time it says "Can't cast `Bitmap` to `PhotoGridItem`".

Comment: Hi, thanks. I posted my updated code. Changed my fragment activity and my adapter a little.

Comment: Till you have same issue, that bitmap can not cast to PhotoGridItem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're only missing this in your `loadSDCard()`:

```
  photoList.add(new PhotoGridItem(bitmap));
```